# JavaScript. Print , как менять размер страницы

Tags: javascript, print

Есть принтер PT-2430PC
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=2430eus
Суть принтера, чтобы распечатывать вот такие номера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой скрипт работает отлично, заходит на печать но я не могу печатать через данные принтер. Для этого нужно, чтобы лист для распечатка не выходил за границы (помечено красной линией)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как это возможно реализовать . Искал в интернете и никак не мог найти никакой информации. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать с помощью css. Есть медиа запросы вида:
   @media print {
        body {
           width: 200px;
        } 
    }
Данные свойства будут применяться после того, как страница отправлена на печать. Например, если пользователь нажал Ctrl + Shift + P. Думаю, идея понятна.